# How to change Celsius to Fahrenheit

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am not quite understanding I am working with Microsoft Visual basic .Net programming and I Have this so far

```
 Sub Main()
        Dim fahrenheit, celsius As Double
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a value for fahrenheit tempature:")
        fahrenheit = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())
        celsius = 5 / 9 * (fahrenheit - 32)
        celsius = Math.Round(celsius, 1)
        Console.WriteLine(fahrenheit & " F = " & celsius & " C")
```

Now I have to add similar lines of code to change Celsius temp to Fahrenheit now do I just repeat what I have or is there another way I am exploring to understand this.I have tried a few things but it is not working.. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong.. and I suppose to use the else if?

```
Sub Main()
    Dim fahrenheit, celsius As Double
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a value for fahrenheit tempature:")
    fahrenheit = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())
    celsius = 5 / 9 * (fahrenheit - 32)
    fahrenheit = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32
    celsius = Math.Round(celsius, 1)
    Console.WriteLine(fahrenheit & " F = " & celsius & " C")
End Sub
```

Ok this is what I have no when the black box comes run when you debug it it only states fahrenheit how can I also get it to read celsius too or do I have to just start clear and make each one as there own.

Comment: I am just learning this and i tried to repeat it and i am looking in my book..is there a web site or something that can explain this better. I am looking at the else if property but it wouldnt make sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a learning exercise, why not produce a function for each?

```
Function GetCelsiusForFahrenheit(ByVal fahrenheit as Double) As Double
    Return (5/9) * (fahrenheit - 32)
End Function

Function GetFahrenheitForCelsius(ByVal celsius as Double) As Double
    Return  (9/5) * celsius  + 32
End Function
```

Comment: It's not a right way it will be (9) / (5*celsius) + 32 but should be (9 / 5)*celsius + 32

Answer (score 0):

why do you not use the "other direction formula" for this? So that would be

```
fahrenheit = (9 / 5 * celsius) + 32
```

Comment: It's not a right way it will be `(9) / (5*celsius) + 32` but should be  `(9 / 5)*celsius + 32`

Comment: no it won't be (9) / (5*celsius) - calculations are made from left to right. So it calculates (9 / 5) * celsius.

Comment: However you should use `9.0` to ensure the initial (constant) division is done with `double` not `int`.

Comment: as far as i know, it is always done with double in C# - it is only done with int if you take \ instead.